# excel-vba set pass for each page tab

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a password to each page of the book, so when I click one page tab, I get an inputBox asking for its pass. Each page has unique password. How can I do it? I tried writing this code at vba ThisWorkbook but it does nothing:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim MySheets As String, Response As String
MySheet = "Sheet1"
If ActiveSheet.Name = inicio Then
ActiveSheet.Visible = False
Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
    If Response = "abc" Then
        Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets(MySheet).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Option Explicit`. Then you would notice, that `inicio` is a variable, and not a name. In general, your code should work, if you write `"inicio"`.

Or something like this, if you ignore the `inicio` and use the `MySheet` string variable that you have already declared:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim MySheet As String, Response As String
    MySheet = "Sheet1"

    If ActiveSheet.Name = MySheet Then
        ActiveSheet.Visible = False
        Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
        If Response = "abc" Then
            Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets(MySheet).Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Or this way, if you want to do it a bit smaller, using the `Sh` parameter and not `ActiveSheet`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Dim mySheet As String: mySheet = "Sheet1"
    Dim response As String

    If Sh.Name = mySheet Then
        response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
        Sh.Visible = CBool(response = "abc")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, I'm new at this. `inicio` is the page's name. I want to get the `InputBox` when clicking in the page tab. I just paste your code at **ThisWorkbook** and its does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Juan - do you have a worksheet named `Sheet1`? What happens when you select it?

Comment: _do you have a worksheet named Sheet1?_ -no, I don't. But I wrote inicio instead.
_What happens when you select it?_ - nothing, it opens normally

Comment: @Juan - and when you select the `inicio` sheet nothing happens?

Comment: it works now! I didn't change nothing haha thank you! One more question: if I want to use different pass for each worksheet, is fine if I just copy-pase in ThisWorkbook changing values?

Comment: @Juan - for different passwords, the easiest way is to declare an array in the `ThisWorkbook` and every time to refer to a different element, depending on the sheet. Something like `Array(Sheet1,Sheet3,Sheet4)` and `Array(pwd1, pwd3,pwd4)`. Thus, for `Sheet4` the password would be `pwd4`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Vityata

Comment: one last question, seriously. What can I do to ask for password to open other worksheet and only show it if the pass is correct? The way you gave asks for pass to work in the worksheet, but it shows anyway. I need to display an InputBox on worksheet click. I'm sorry if I'm explaining bad

Comment: `Sh.Visible = CBool(response = "abc")` should be only visible if the password is `abc`, I do not get it.

Comment: sorry, I mean: by that way it asks for pass when I click on the worksheet, but showing the page while InputBox. I want the same but showing the page **after** inserting the password. Did I explain ok?

Comment: @Juan - write         `If Sh.Count >1 Then Sh.Visible = False` somewhere on the top.

Comment: it doesn't work, but don't worry, you did help a lot at this point! I will post a solution for this when I solve it. Thank you!

Comment: @Juan -  I am not worried, thank you. In general, you may ask a separate question, although it should be working...